# "This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress." - Why?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

i am new to this backgroundworker thing
i have read some articles about how to create one
this is what it produced

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap imgbox = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image);

        int imgHeight = imgbox.Height;
        int imgWidth = imgbox.Width;

        int counter = 1;

        MinMaxWidth = imgWidth - 50;
        MaxWidth = imgWidth;

        try
        {
            Color c;
            //Color c2;

            for (int i = 0; i < imgbox.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imgbox.Height; j++)
                {
                    c = imgbox.GetPixel(i, j);
                    string cn = c.Name;
                    counter++;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(counter);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("SUCESSFULLY DONE");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

but when i started the DoWork event. this error showed up

> This `BackgroundWorker` states that it doesn't report progress.
>     Modify `WorkerReportsProgess` to state that it does report progress.

ijust follow what the tutorial says
what would be the problem?, is there something that i forgot?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As the error suggests, set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property of your `BackgroundWorker` component to `true`.