# Updating a Label with the backgroundworker progress

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am reading line by line console of an external exe with the help of a backgroundworker, i am assigning each line of console to a label. the problem is the label is not updating with the console line. code is given below

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = EXELOCATION;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = Program.path;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = exeProcess.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result;
                while ((result = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // object param = result;

                    e.Result = result;
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(i++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}

private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = e.ToString();
    label.Refresh();
}
```

how can i solve this issue

Comment: Are you sure it's **not happening?** Is it by chance that the file is so small that it happens too fast?

Comment: is this WinForms or WPF application?

Comment: the code raise this error "This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report progress".

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448612/this-backgroundworker-states-that-it-doesnt-report-progress-why

Comment: So was the exception message sufficient for you to conclude that you must add bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
label2.Invoke(new Action(() => { label2.Text = e.ToString(); }));
label2.Invoke(new Action(() => { label2.Refresh(); }));
```

Comment: @thanx alot you save my day

Answer (score 0):

That code probably doesn't work because you're trying to update an UI element from a non-UI thread (aka background thread).

If you're using WPF, you should use the `Dispatcher` to request that the label be changed in the UI thread. If you're using another framework, try that framework's equivalent class.

In your ProgressChanged method, try this instead:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  () => {
    label.Text = e.ToString();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in another thread (and you are in a winforms application), you might need to use the [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)

```
public void UpdateProgress (int progress)
{
  if (label.InvokeRequired)
  { 
     this.Invoke(()=> UpdateProgress(progress));
  }
  else
  {
     label.Text = progress.ToString();
  }
}
```

This method checks whether it's run on the UI thread, and if it is not, it calls itself on the UI thread. If it is already on the UI thread, it simply updates the label.