# This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Where is my mistake? I think everything is fine but still I see this exception:

> Exception {"This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report
>   progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report
>   progress."}.Exception wasthrown in
>   _worker.ReportProgress((int)(progressPercentage*100)).

Can somebody recommend me a ftp server with rich data for test download and upload?

Here is my code:

```
    this._worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    this._worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    this._worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    this._worker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    this._worker.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;

using (FileStream fs = new    FileStream(Path.Combine(this._ftpInfo.SaveDirectory, this._ftpInfo.FileName), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                    {


                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    int byteTotal = 0;

                    while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, len);
                        byteTotal += len;
                        double index = (double)(byteTotal);
                        double total = (double)buffer.Length;
                        double progressPercentage = (index / total);
                        _worker.ReportProgress((int)(progressPercentage*100));

                    }
                    fs.Close();
```

Comment: It's written [in the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress): The [WorkerReportsProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress) property is set to `false` (or never set, `false` is the default).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress." - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448612/this-backgroundworker-states-that-it-doesnt-report-progress-why)

Answer (score 2):

You have this line twice:

```
this._worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

One of those was probably supposed to be:

```
this._worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

On a side note, consider [using `Task.Run` with `IProgress<T>` instead of `BackgroundWorker`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html). The resulting code will be shorter and more type-safe.